# Signing Firefox Addon error

Tags: firefox, curl, firefox-addon

I have tried to generate the JWT token for my addon using the following node.js script

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var issuedAt  = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var payload = {
    iss: 'user:5617820:496',
    jti: Math.random().toString(),
    iat: issuedAt,
    exp: issuedAt + 60,
};
var secret = '.mysecret.'
// store this securely.
var token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, {algorithm: 'HS256',// HMAC-SHA256 signing algorithm
});
console.log(token);
```

Then I use this token to issue the command:

> C:\curl>curl.exe
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/api/v3/addons/EasyFa@EasyFa.txt/versions/1.0.1-signed
>   -g -XPUT --form 'upload=build/easyfa-1.0-fx.xpi' -H 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0...HI'

but there is an error of:

- curl: (6) Could not resolve host: JWT
- curl: (6) Could not resolve
  host: eyJ0.....

Any ideas what I am missing here?
Thanks